# Generate SQL query from NSDictionary

Tags: sql, swift, swift3

I would like to generate SQL statement from my Dictionary object. Because i have to eliminate the update process of empty string in corresponding column. i can do this  via Swift code but doing this repeat action not good. is there any way to do this via SQL Statement?.

i have found some link on StackOverflow.
[Asp.net link](https://forums.asp.net/t/1942071.aspx?Ignore%20NULL%20or%20blank%20values%20in%20update%20sql%20string)

and [MySQL StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844701/mysql-update-query-how-to-skip-empty-values)

like sample example in python code

```
def insertFromDict(table, dict):
    """Take dictionary object dict and produce sql for 
    inserting it into the named table"""
    sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + table
    sql += ' ('
    sql += ', '.join(dict)
    sql += ') VALUES ('
    sql += ', '.join(map(dictValuePad, dict))
    sql += ');'
    return sql

def dictValuePad(key):
    return '%(' + str(key) + ')s'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let r = sqlFrom(dict: ["name" : "String", "type" : "sort"], for: "MyTable")
print(r)
```

Needed function:

```
func sqlFrom(dict : [String : String], for table : String) -> String {
    let keys = dict.keys.joined(separator: ", ")
    var values = dict.values.joined(separator: "', '")
    values = """
    '\(values)'
    """
    let sql = "INSERT INTO \(table) ( \(keys) ) VALUES ( \( values) );"
    return sql
}
```

Check result [here](https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/):

Answer (score 0):

Following method will do the job, but will not prevent you from sql injections

```
func insertStatement(table: String, dict: [String : Any]) -> String {
    let values: [String] = dict.values.compactMap { value in
        if value is String || value is Int || value is Double {
            return "'\(value)'"
        } else if let date = value as? Date {
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
            return "'" + dateFormatter.string(from: date) + "'"
        }
        // handle other types if necessary

        return nil
    }

    return "INSERT INTO \(table) (" + dict.keys.joined(separator: ",") + ") VALUES (" + values.joined(separator: ",") + ")"
}
```

Usage:
`insertStatement(table: "test_table", dict: ["id": 8, "name" : "John", "age" : Date()])`

Output: `INSERT INTO test_table(id,age,name) VALUES ('8','2019-04-24','John')`

To prevent from SQL injections you have to use prepared statements to bind values, such as in the PHP's PDO library, like so:

```
func insertStatement(table: String, dict: [String : Any]) {
    let columns = dict.keys.joined(separator: ",")
    let values = dict.keys.map({ ":" + $0 }).joined(separator: ",")

    // build the statement
    let sql = "INSERT INTO " + table + "(" + columns + ") VALUES (" + values + ")"

    var bind: [String : Any] = [:]
    for (column, value) in dict {
        bind[":\(column)"] = value
    }
}
```